# Accessing a window scoped bean inside a servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, managed-bean

I would like to retrieve in my servlet a bean with scope window.

does anybody know how to do it?

many thanks for your help.

Comment: What framework provides that specific scope?

Comment: Icefaecs 3. I use @CustomScoped("#{window}") on my bean.